# Running set of code in loop after reading from a list of values stored

Tags: r, for-loop, grouping

I read the following datasets:

```
 LosAngeles <- read.csv("Los Angeles.csv",header=FALSE)
 Chicago <- read.csv("Chicago.csv",header=FALSE)
 Memphis <- read.csv("Memphis.csv",header=FALSE)
 Houston <- read.csv("Houston.csv",header=FALSE)
 Pittsburgh <- read.csv("Pittsburgh.csv",header=FALSE)
 Seattle <- read.csv("Seattle.csv",header=FALSE)
```

Each dataset has same number of variables and observations and looks something like this:

```
    Week       Item    Sales 
 01/1/2011      A       129
 07/1/2011      A       140
 14/1/2011      A       133
 21/1/2011      A       189
 ...           ...      ...
 01/12/2013     Z       324
 07/12/2013     Z       210
 14/12/2013     Z       155
 21/12/2013     Z       386
 28/12/2013     Z       266
```

For each one of the datasets I want to create insample and holdoutsample by grouping every "Item". So, I run this bit of code:

```
  List3 <- by(LosAngeles, LosAngeles$Item, function(x) x[1:120,])
  InLosAngeles <- do.call('rbind', List3)
  List4 <- by(LosAngeles, LosAngeles$Item, function(x) x[121:152,])
  OutLosAngeles <- do.call('rbind', List4)
```

How do I form my code so that I have a loop to just replace "LosAngeles" by every other city name. I was thinking to store all the names of the cities in a list:

```
 list <-c("LosAngeles", "Chicago", "Memphis","Houston","Pittsburgh","Seattle")
```

but I am not sure how to write a loop to call each city from the list and replace that name in the code above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to approach it.

### List of Cities

Instead of having separate variables for each city, you could read them into a `list` of structures and deal with each element of the list, as follows:

```
cities <- c("Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Memphis", "Houston", "Pittsburgh", "Seattle")
allcities <- lapply(cities,
                    function(cityname) read.csv(paste0(cityname, '.csv'),
                                                header = FALSE))
names(allcities) <- cities # for reference, not strictly required
```

You can now loop over each element of the list using either `lapply` again:

```
results <- lapply(allcities, function(city) {
    list(
      insample = do.call(rbind, by(city, city$Item, function(x) x[1:120,])),
      outsample = do.call(rbind, by(city, city$Item, function(x) x[121:152,]))
    )
})
```

(Alternatively, you might use a `for` loop if you'd rather.) You could now reference `results$`Los Angeles`$insample` and `results$Houston$outsample`, for instance. (Note that LA is referenced inside backticks because of its space. Easily remedied by changing the file-naming conventions.)

### Using `get` and `assign`

Another approach -- admittedly frowned upon by many -- is to reference the variable names indirectly. For example:

```
## do all of the read.csv() stuff you previously did
## (notice that I'm using the no-space version of LA this time)
cities <- c("LosAngeles", "Chicago", "Memphis", "Houston", "Pittsburgh", "Seattle")

for (city in cities) {
    tmpvar <- get(city) # env might need to be adjusted
    assign(paste0('In', city),
           do.call(rbind, by(tmpvar, tmpvar$Item, function(x) x[1:120,]))
    assign(paste0('Out', city),
           do.call(rbind, by(tmpvar, tmpvar$Item, function(x) x[121:152,])))
}
```

This is geared better towards console work and not necessarily scripted work, though safeguards can be put in place to ensure it works smoothly unsupervised. I tend to not like this approach, but offer it in case shifting to the `*apply` family of functions is not good for you.

*(Caveat: this is conceptual code, I haven't tested it with actual data sources, etc.)*

Comment: The comment about 'in' versus 'In' from @germcd's answer applies here, too. (I did caveat it, after all ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
for( i in 1:length(list)){
List3 <- by(eval(parse(text = list[i])), eval(parse(text = list[i]))$Item, function(x) x[1:120,])
in = paste( "In", list[i], sep = "")
assign( in,  do.call('rbind', List3) )
List4 <- by(LosAngeles, LosAngeles$Item, function(x) x[121:152,])
out = paste( "Out", list[i], sep = "")
assign( in,  do.call('rbind', List4) )
}
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for a quick response! I tried running it but got this error `unexpected 'in' in "  assign(in"`.I changed the List4 bit too accordingly ofcourse!

Comment: try callling `in` `In`